# Is it OK to send messages to self during initialization (and deallocation)?

Tags: objective-c

[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html) and [others](http://qualitycoding.org/objective-c-init/) recommend against using accessor methods during initialization as the object may be in an inconsistent state. What is the general best practice with regards to sending messages to that class during initialization? It's quite common, even [recommended](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/) to use designated initializers. So in a case where you have a UIView subclass, and that subclass has a UILabel subview, what is the standard practice?

```
-(instancetype)init {
  if(self = [super init]) {
    _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    [self addSubview:_label];
  }
}
```

Another common approach is to have a "convenience" method for initializing your object. This method would be called from all initializers (e.g. `init`, `initWithFrame:`...):

```
-(instancetype)init {
  if(self = [super init]) {
    [self setupView];
  }
}


-(void)setupView {
  _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
  [self addSubview:_label];      
}
```

Or would, in this case, adding subviews to the view be better suited in a different method? Override `layoutSubviews` perhaps?

Comment: FYI - `layoutSubviews` should do just that, layout the subviews. You should not be creating, adding, or removing subviews in `layoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem in doing this:

```
-(instancetype)init {
  if(self = [super init]) {
    _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    [self addSubview:_label];
  }
}
```

After you run the `[super init]` line, the runtime has already created and fully initialized your object. It's perfectly safe to call `self` afterwards.

Regarding your last question:

- adding subviews right in the `init` loads them at the same time you instantiate your view. They're ready for use everywhere else in the class.
- adding subviews somewhere else (like in `layoutSubviews`) is like lazy-loading: the subviews are loaded only when necessary, but you must be careful not to reference them before they're available.

Comment: If the object is fully initialized, why then is it not recommended to use accessors during initialization? Do you have any link to the docs for your answer?

Comment: You can call methods on `self` like `addSubview`, it's just not recommended to call property setters/getters until the object is fully initialized. I believe it has to do with any potential Key-Value observer, which cannot subscribe until the object is ready.